# Oracle job that runs a batch file

Tags: oracle, batch-file, plsql, jobs

So I have in my DB a user, that I want to use to run a. bat file. The easiest way to do this, was to use an Oracle Job.

So I created my job, but when I try to run it, it gives me the following errors :

```
ORA-27370: job slave failed to launch a job of type EXECUTABLE
ORA-27300: OS system dependent operation:accessing job scheduler service failed with status: 2
ORA-27301: OS failure message: The system cannot find the file specified.
ORA-27302: failure occurred at: sjsec 6a
ORA-27303: additional information: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Out of curiosity, I created the same job, with the exact settings with the SYS user in its schema(yes, i know that this is not recommanded...), and when I ran the job, it worked perfectly.
So I though that there are probably some permission involved so I gave my user, all the system priviledges and roles that the SYS user had, to see if this is the problem.

However, I got the same errors.. Any ideas why this works in sys schema, and not in my user's schema, although the user has all the priviledges set ?:|

Comment: .bat - so your database is installed on a Windows OS?

Comment: Also, what version of the database?  What does the batch file do?

Comment: yes i use Windows. DB is oracle 11g standard. The batch file does a backup of the DB using the exp tool from oracle

Comment: whos the owner of the job? (select * from dba_scheduler_jobs) SYS?  Also, can you post the scheduler setup code?

Comment: @tbone when the job is created with the sys, it is the sys, when it is created with the other user, it is the other user

Answer (score 3):

You have not given any information on what exact command you're running. We'll have to guess.

From your description, I would say the behaviour is typical of **"SYS is special"**. In the [DBA guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/schedover003.htm#ADMIN13360), we can see that an external local job will behave differently if the account is SYS when no credential is provided.

So I'm guessing that you're running your job with `DBMS_SCHEDULER` without credential and that the default non-SYS OS account has not the same OS rights as the Oracle installer account.

Try to [create a credential](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse002.htm#CIAHDDCJ) with [`DBMS_SCEDULER.CREATE_CREDENTIAL`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_sched.htm#BABCAEAC) with a sufficiently-privileged OS account and assign this credential to your job.